# Semi Circle Pie Chart in Android Application

Tags: android

Can anyone please help me out with creating a semi circle pie chart in an android application or is there any library that I can implement to render a semi circle pie chart similar to the attached image..

[image]

Comment: @Saket89 did you find solution for it?

Comment: @Sapna Sharma Yes, you need to edit the angles in the PieChart class provided by MPCHART Library https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Answer (score 2):

edit in this link [MagicPie](https://github.com/AlexandrGraschenkov/MagicPie) 
Its a third library that works with `Core Animation`.

Changing the properties '`startAngle`' and '`endAngle`' of the the property '`PieLayer`' in the `UIView` where the Pies are drawn.

```
self.layer.startAngle = 0;
self.layer.endAngle = 180;
```

refer link[here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30843256/edit)

Comment: then you have to use achart engine and suggestion given by hardeep. and as per my knowledge there is no library for half circle chart, you have to edit the available librarys yourself and use it

Comment: Exactly you have to edit library in accordance to your need.. :) Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

The following mentioned library will do your task

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

also go through

http://androidplot.com/